# Calculating a commission rate based on a date sold when there have been multiple changes to commission rates

Tags: date, google-sheets, formula

I would like to calculate a commission rate based on a date sold when there have been multiple changes to commission rates. Ie; when I sold a product on 16/1/2023 - return the value that I should have been paid at at that time ($250). Thank you xxx

A1: (Date Sold) 16/1/2023

> > > B2 - (formula needed to return $250)

C1:(Commission rate Date:) 1/4/2022
D2: $200

C2:(Commission rate Date:) 1/1/20223
D2: $250

C3:(Commission rate Date:) 1/4/20223
D3: $300

C4:(Commission rate Date:) 1/7/20223
D4: $350

I can't work out the "between values" formula

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLOOKUP, to find the value in a sorted range of dates, and return the next column:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,C:D,2,1)
```

[image]

Or, similar approach with XLOOKUP:

```
=XLOOKUP(A1,C:C,D:D,,-1)
```